# PySpark hangs on S3 read

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, pyspark

I want to read files from S3 with PySpark (local installation, not EMR). The problem is that it freezes on read, without any timeout or error.

Versions:

- PySpark 3.2.2
- Hadoop 3.3.1
- Hadoop-AWS 3.3.1 .jar
- AWS Java SDK bundle 1.12.136 .jar (also tried 1.11.901)

JAR files are put directly in `SPARK_HOME/jars` directory, so I don't need to specify them separately here (this approach worked for my other Spark jobs with other JAR dependencies).

My PySpark code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# filled in code
aws_access_key_id = ""
aws_secret_access_key = ""

spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("Test S3 app")

    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", aws_access_key_id)
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", aws_secret_access_key)
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "eu-central-1.amazonaws.com")
    
    .getOrCreate()
)

# here the execution hangs
df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://bucket/file.parquet")

df.show()
```

What can I do with this? I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761761/s3fs-connector-with-pyspark-3-2-hadoop-3-3-1-hangs-on-spark-read-load), but there is working no solution there.

Using the same credentials and S3 path with boto3 works and downloads the file in less than a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some experimentation (when you wait, the query times out and prints error, but after a long time) I came up with the solution - it suffices to set:

```
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com")
```

Note that `s3.` **has** to be used, not `s3a.`, suggested in some places that I've seen. With this modification, everything works.

Comment: what`s the stack trace? it shouldn't block for that long...if it does there's too much retrying going on